# SharePoint Add in Permissions for Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to register an add in in SharePoint online where I can run search queries. I've tried various permission xml's and cannot seem to get it to work.

I've been going here assign the xml...
https://{sharepointsite}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

My latest try was this...

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="false">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

which results in "Application does not have administrative permissions in tenant"

I've also tried this which doesn't work either...

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="false">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

and this...

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

So, my question is - what is the proper permission xml so search queries can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

I heard about this. It's a long story of permission cooking for app. You can read topic like this - [MSDN Archive Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vesku/using-add-in-only-app-only-permissions-with-search-queries-in-sharepoint-online). You need to add the permission XML in the admin site collection. I hope this help you.

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Tenancy scope permission.

```
http://sharepoint/content/tenant
```

Please refer to following document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-in-permissions-in-sharepoint#types-of-add-in-permissions-and-permission-scopes

Comment: Would you add the tenancy permission on the admin permissions page  https://xxxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx like this...
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"><AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" /></AppPermissionRequests>

And then go to the non-admin site to assign a search permission as well like this?
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="false"><AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" /></AppPermissionRequests>